# Delphi XE6, 3D array of records with boolean member fields, won't build

Tags: arrays, delphi, compiler-errors, boolean, record

Simple example:

```
type
  TGm = record
    Rm,Nc,Sc,Wc,Ec,Su,Sd:boolean;
  end;

var
  Dm: Array[1..20] of Array[1..20] of Array[1..20] of TGm;
  Gm: TGm;

...

if (Dm(z,y-1,x).Ec) then Gm.Wc := TRUE;
```

When I try to build, that last line will be marked and two errors are shown:

```
'$1' does not contain a member named 'Ec'
Type of expression must be BOOLEAN
```

Am I missing something vitally simple here?

And, yes, I'm generating a dungeon ;-)

Comment: The brackets... vitally simple, yes. The compiler error is strange though...

Comment: @Sertac: I guess the compiler sees it as some kind of anonymous type, internally called `$1`, probably the internal primary row of the Dm type. I guess that is because the declaration is `array[] of array[] of array[] of ...`, which is unusual. Normally, you have `array[..,..,..] of ...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using parenthesis where brackets are required.  It should look like this instead:

```
if Dm[z][y-1][x].Ec then Gm.Wc := TRUE;
```

I would suggest using a single multi-dimensional array instead:

```
var
  Dm: Array[1..20, 1..20, 1..20] of TGm;
  Gm: TGm;

...

  if Dm[z,y-1,x].Ec then Gm.Wc := TRUE;
```

Comment: Could you please explain what first compiler message means? I'm confused, usually delphi compiler messages are very friendly...

Comment: I can't reproduce the error you have shown in my XE6.  The line in question fails with "E2066 Missing operator or semicolon" instead.